# Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem

Tags: nginx, ssl, yaml, puppet, lets-encrypt

I am hoping that someone will be able to provide some help on this issue that I am facing.

I am working with a server that has two VM's on it. I have Puppet Master on one with my control repository. And on the other VM is my Puppet Agent.

When I am running `puppet agent -t --no-noop` on the puppet agent I am seeing the following error message:

```
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/profiles/manifests/letsencrypt.pp, line: 27)
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/profiles/manifests/letsencrypt.pp, line: 27)
Wrapped exception:
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem
Error: /Stage[main]/Profiles::Letsencrypt/File[/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.evolvedbinary.com/cert.pem]/ensure: change from 'absent' to 'file' failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/profiles/manifests/letsencrypt.pp, line: 27)
```

This then leads to nginx to fail as the certificate cannot be loaded.

```
Error: Systemd start for nginx failed!
journalctl log for nginx:
-- Logs begin at Fri 2023-08-18 12:11:49 BST, end at Thu 2023-09-07 12:08:25 BST. --
Sep 07 12:08:25 test-web systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Sep 07 12:08:25 test-web nginx[312617]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem": BIO_new_file() failed
```

So, What I can tell from this is that the file `cert.pem` is not being created. And this is then leading to error and the nginx failing. So, I have tried creating the file though my letsencrypt.pp file but this failed. So I tried to adding the `force => true` command to the `ensure => file` statement. This still did not work. The file was still not being created. So I manually added the file on the puppet agent VM using `vim`. I now know the file is there (even if it is a blank file). I should now expect to see a different error than what I was seeing. But It was the same error.

I will add the letsencrypt.pp file and the file containing my nginx script below.

letsencrypt.pp

```
class profiles::letsencrypt {

package { 'cron':
  ensure => installed
}

class { 'letsencrypt':
  require => Package['cron']
}

file { '/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf':
  ensure => file,
}

file {'/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem':
  ensure => file,
}

file {'/etc/letsencrypt/live':
  ensure => directory, 
} 

file {'/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com':
  ensure => directory,
}

file {'/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem':
  ensure => file,
}

include 'letsencrypt'
include 'letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare'
# include 'letsencrypt::plugin::nginx'

  letsencrypt::certonly { '*.test.domain.com':
    domains              => ['*.test.domain.com'],
    plugin               => 'dns-cloudflare',
    manage_cron          => true,
    cron_hour            => [0,12],
    cron_minute          => '30',
    cron_before_command  => 'service nginx stop',
    cron_success_command => '/bin/systemctl reload nginx.service',
    #suppress_cron_output => true,
    require              => Class['nginx'],
  }
}
```

test-web.domain.com.yaml

```
---
classes:
   - roles::www

# UFW Rules
ufw::rules:
  'Allow HTTP':
    action: allow
    to_ports_app: 80
    proto: tcp
  'Allow HTTPS':
    action: allow
    to_ports_app: 443
    proto: tcp

# nginx rules
nginx::nginx_servers:
  'www.test.domain.com':
    server_name: [
      '*.test.domain.com',
      'test.domain.com',
    ]
    ipv6_enable: true
    ssl: true
    http2: 'on'
    ssl_redirect: true
    ssl_cert: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem'
    ssl_key: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem'
    www_root: '/var/www/www.test.domain.com'
    server_cfg_ssl_append:
      include: '/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf'
      ssl_dhparam: '/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem'
# letsencrypt
letsencrypt::email: 'sysops@domain.com'
letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare::email: 'user.@email.com'
```

Please be aware that this I have replaced the domain name and email address with test.domain or user@email, This is not the case on the Server and the VM's.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: "No such file or directory" means that an attempt to open the file failed, but that message is sometimes misleading.  Other kinds of failure-to-open sometimes elicit the same message, such as a permissions failure on the file or one of the directories in the path to it.  If you are running the agent as root (which generally you need to do) then you could still get a permission failure courtesy of SELinux.  By default, that would be logged, so you might want to check your system log.

Comment: I have now been able to create the file that I needed I found a small grammar issue that was creating the issue of not being able to create the file. However, the issue that I am now facing is that I cannot seem to populate the file with the certificate. I am getting a trusted certificate issue. Please see below: 
` nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate` `"/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/cert.pem":` `PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL:` `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start` `line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)`
Which is the second issue that I have stated in the question.

Comment: You would ordinarily use either the `content` property or the `source` property of the [`File` resource](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/types/file.html) to explain to Puppet what the file should contain.  More likely `source` in your case, to copy a certificate stored somewhere on the Puppet server.